# Encargado del filtrado de datos en asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendoui

Tengo una aplicacion web **MVC** y contiene un **GRID** con framework **KENDOUI** donde muestra todos los datos de la tabla "Paciente", deseo **filtrar** los datos a mostrar en la tabla según el usuario identificado el cual ya esta implementado con winform, hice la busqueda pero indican que se puede hacer desde la vista **.cshtml**, otros que es mejor desde el controlador, cual seria la manera recomendable o como lo estipula el patrón MVC en asp.net.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como es eso que esta implementado en winform ? no es una aplicacion web que tiene que ver que se haya realizado en winform

Comment: Perdón Leandro, con decir winform indicaba la forma de logearse, recien estoy formando mis conocimientos en .NET y lei que existen diferentes maneras de tomar el tema de autenticacion (ejm: webapi) y form es una de las maneras mas "antiguas" segun lei, y no sabia si esto afecta. Perdón nuevamente.

Comment: ahh era la autenticacion form o sea tiene una pagina para solicitar usuario y password. En ese caso mientras puedas tener el dato del usuario autenticado no habria problemas ya que usarias ese dato como filtro de la informacion

Answer (score 2):

El filtro debes implementar en el `action` el `controller`, no puedes filtrar en el `cshtml` si esperas retorar un json como respuesta.

```
public ActionResult tblpaciente_Read(){

    IQueryable<tblpaciente> tblpacientes = db.tblpacientes.Where(p=> p.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);

    //resto codigo

    return Json(result)
}
```

No estoy seguro como implementas la seguridad del sitio, quizas lo del User.Identity debas cambiarlo para adaptarlo a tu implemetacion, pero seria en el action donde implementarías el filtro sobre la propiedad de la entidad.